# creating line breaks after commas - before desired line width

Tags: text-formatting

In a file like:

```
ruler    1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\usage{
function(
parameter,
parameterparameter,
parameter = parameter,
parameter = p,
parameter = para,
parameter = para,
paramete = p,
parameterparameter = pa,
parameter = p,
p = pa,
param,
parameterpara = par,
paramet = par,
parameter = param,
parameterpa = param,
...
more lines
```

I want to concatenate lines from line with "usage" to the line with "...", and then, create new line breaks after commas before the 80th character (column).

For now, I manage to break lines after the nth comma, but it is not efficient because in many cases a lot of spaces remain after, say, the 3rd comma. So I want the comma before the line break to be as close as possible to the 80th character.

```
sed -i -r '/usage/{:a;N;/\.\.\./!ba;s/\n//g}' filename.txt
sed -i 's/\(\([^,]\+,\)\{3\}\)/\1\n/g;s/\n/\n/g' filename.txt
```

I looked at "par", "fold" and "fmt" documentation without success. "fold" gets near but splits lines in space not comma:

```
sed -i -r '/usage/{:a;N;/\.\.\./!ba;s/\n//g}' filename.txt
fold -s filename.txt | tee filename.txt
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what output you expect from this input file so we can understand exactly what you need.

Comment: Please show us the _actual_ output you want, not a command that produces something "similar". We need to know what you need in order to be able to help you, don't make us guess.

Comment: Also, sorry, I just rejected your suggested edit to Stéphane's answer because I didn't realize it was you, the question asker, who suggested it. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lazy variant, using `perl`'s slurp mode:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e '
  s{\\usage.*?\n\.\.\.\n}{
    ($r = $&) =~ s/\n//g;
    $r =~ s/\G.{0,79}(,|.$)\K/\n/g;
    $r
  }gse' your-file
```

Which gives:

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\usage{function(parameter,parameterparameter,parameter = parameter,
parameter = p,parameter = para,parameter = para,paramete = p,
parameterparameter = pa,parameter = p,p = pa,param,parameterpara = par,
paramet = par,parameter = param,parameterpa = param,...
more lines
```

Comment: Why did you add an extra line of numbers to the question? That changes the OP's file. Is that line actually present? If not, please undo that edit, we shouldn't change the OP's data since you never know how that could affect an answer.

Comment: @terdon, that's a ruler to show where the 80th column is. It's easier to read with that extra line. I don't expect that line is part of the input.

Comment: could you comment the code?

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^\\usage/,/^\.\.\./ { if (length(line $0) >= 80) { print line; line = $0 } else line = line $0; next  }; line != "" { print line; line = "" }; 1' file
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\usage{function(parameter,parameterparameter,parameter = parameter,
parameter = p,parameter = para,parameter = para,paramete = p,
parameterparameter = pa,parameter = p,p = pa,param,parameterpara = par,
paramet = par,parameter = param,parameterpa = param,...
more lines
```

The `awk` code, annotated:

```awk
/^\\usage/,/^\.\.\./ {
        # This block triggers for all lines between a line
        # starting with "\usage" and another line
        # starting with "..."

        # If our saved output line and the current line together
        # is longer or equal to 80 characters, print the output
        # line and reset it to the current line.  Else, add the
        # current line to the end of the saved output line.
        if (length(line $0) >= 80) {
                print line
                line = $0
        } else
                line = line $0

        # Skip to next line of input.
        next
}

# If we get here and the saved output line is
# non-empty, then there is data to output, so
# do that.
line != "" { print line; line = "" }

# Print all input.
1
```